# Would a fast moving (approaching $c$) stream of particles be affected by the gravitational pull of a gas giant?

Tags: gravity, mass

I was inspired by [this SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100221/).  Would the gravitational field of a gas giant (such as Yavin IV) have an effect on the super laser (i.e. slow it down, change the direction), or is the mass so insignificant on the laser beam that it is negligible?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Did you try anything to figure out the answer yourself? If so, you should mention it in the question. We expect people to do a certain amount of investigating on their own before posting here, and the answer to this _should_ be easily available in many other places.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Gravity bends spacetime and anything occupying it.

Edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens